# Postgres execute function if exists

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is it possible to write a select statement that executes function if exists ?

```
SELECT COALESCE (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'func_name') THEN null  ELSE false END, (SELECT func_name()   ))

OR 
                   select 1                 
                    WHERE EXISTS (
                      select * from pg_proc where proname = 'func_name'
                    ) AND EXISTS (
                        select func_name(); 
                    )
```

Above are ofcourse wrong statements but just to give you an idea. Is it possible?? I am using Postgres 10.1 so its not the latest

Comment: What does the function return?

Comment: its a void function .. just refreshes some views..

Comment: I am running Postgres 10.1 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably get away with using `query_to_xml()`

```
select query_to_xml('select func_name()', false, true, '')
where exists (select * 
              from pg_proc
              where proname = 'func_name'
                and pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace)
```